# Fill/Initialize vector with Objects in C++

Tags: c++, object, vector, initialization

so first of all here is my code:

```
#include "Data.h"
#include "Ant.h"

using namespace std;

#define NUMBERANTS 500

int main() {

init();

vector<Ant> antarmy;
antarmy.reserve(NUMBERANTS);
int currentAntNumber = 1;

fill(antarmy.begin(), antarmy.end(), Ant());

for each (Ant ant in antarmy) {
    ant.setNumber(currentAntNumber);
    currentAntNumber++;
    ant.antRoute(ant);
}


system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

I have a vector of objects (Ant) and I defined the size of the vector. Now I want to initiliaze it with the number of Objects. But

```
fill(antarmy.begin(), antarmy.end(), Ant());
```

doesnt work somehow. So what do I have to change?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You reserved space but you never resized it, its size is still 0.

Comment: `vector<Ant> antarmy( number_of_ants );`

Comment: Please learn the difference between [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) and [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).

Comment: `reserve` != `resize`.

Comment: Also `for each (Ant ant in antarmy)`? That's not valid C++.

Comment: My Programming Skills are just really bad sorry for that :/

Comment: Doesn't look like the programming's bad. You just need to brush up on the syntax.